# Delete older logs within a log file

Tags: logs

I have multiple log file appended every day since 2 years, want to cleanup the logs older than 90days in each log file. Can i include dates for the past few year? Like 90..1000 to delete files older than 3 months to past few years?

Comment: What is the data format? I have logs with `2023-04-09T04:02:02.876067-04:00`, `2023-04-09T08:13:45Z`, `[Oct 23 09:22:37.912]`, `[09/Apr/2023:09:50:53 -0400]`, and `[Sun Apr 09 04:02:26.077019 2023]` and that is with checking only a few files. In looking closer, your question is unclear. Do you have a single log file that is appended to or do you have a directory with multiple files?

Comment: `logrotate` is probably a better solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Managing log files by hand is complex. How is your log file used? Is it periodically updated or does a long running process (daemon) have it open constantly? If the latter, you'll have to do something (signal, or restart) with the daemon. Read the `man` page for the daemon.

When the logfile (`big.log`) is not open by any process (check via `sudo lsof $PWD/big.log`), use the `date` command (`man date`) with the "`--date="today - 90 days"`" and "`+`" formatting options to produce 90 days ago's in the same format as used in `big.log`.

```
# Warning: bash pseudo-code due to fuzziness of spec
# Warning: run any derived code through https://shellcheck.net
# **UNTESTED**
# You: Backup big.log, Just In Case

longago="$(date --date="today - 90 days" +"%...")"
# find the line number of the first occurence of the long ago date. 
# only want the 1st match, 
# only want the line number (up to the colon)
firstkeep="$(grep -n "$longago" big.log | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1)"
# left as an exercise: what if there are no logs on $longago?
# simple check? 
[[ -z "$firstkeep" ]] && \
    error ...
# now, just keep from $firstkeep to the end
tail -n "$firstkeep" big.log
 >small.log

# now, check small.log (add tests)
wc -l big.log small.log

# when you're satisfied with small.log

# If the first mv works, do the second
mv big.log big.log.old && mv small.log big.log

# finally, when you're satisfied with the new, smaller big.log.
df.;rm big.log.old;df .
```

All of these commands have `man` pages. Read them as needed along with `man bash`.